# display data name instead of id property

Tags: php, laravel

I can't get the name property to display in my index always showing error

> "Function name must be a string"

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $accounts = Account::with('student')->get();
    return $accounts('Student_id');

    $student = Student::find($id, ['id', 'studentname']);
    return view('accounts.index',compact('accounts'));
}
```

**Model**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'accountname',
    'Student_id',    
];

public function student() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Student::class);
}
```

View Code:

```
<tbody>
      @foreach ($accounts as $account)
         <tr>
             <td>{{ $account->accountname }}</td>
             <td> {{$account->student->studentname}}</td>
         </tr>
      @endforeach
</tbody>
```

I'm trying to display the `studentname` instead of `Student_id` using one to many relationship.

this is the Error

[image]

Note: but if i changed this **{{$account->student->studentname}}** to this **{{$account->Student_id}}** it work but only showing the id not the name.

Comment: `dd($accounts);` in your controller and see the result first!

Comment: how? can teach me ? sorry i'm still new to this one

Comment: Only `return $accounts;` in your controller n see the result what it return?

Comment: Also you have return statement before `$student = Student::find($id, ['id', 'studentname']);` and it's not run after return statement!

Comment: Remove `return $accounts('Student_id');` why you have 2 returns and also this statement is wrong`

Comment: can u arrange my code properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove these lines:

```
return $accounts('Student_id');
$student = Student::find($id, ['id', 'studentname']);
```

Also, since you're not using a standard foreign key name, you need to add it to the definition:

```
public function student()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Student::class, 'Student_id');
}
```

Also, it's a good idea to [follow Laravel naming conventions](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions) which you will find in my repo and rename `Student_id` to `student_id`. In this case, your relationship will work without defining a foreign key.

**Update**

The solution for the third issue you have is:

```
<td> {{ optional($account->student)->studentname}}</td>
```

Comment: bro still showing the same erorr and it is highlighting this word

Comment: return $accounts('Student_id');

Comment: @Copain it's not related to the code you've shown. Please show full view and full error messsage.

Comment: i did already the one you suggest but still showing this error "Function name must be a string"

Comment: @Copain if you want help, show the view and error message.

Comment: @Copain you should add it to your question (edit it).

Comment: @Copain Thanks. The error shows where exactly the problem is. You need to remove the line which is highlighted in IDE. I've updated the answer.

Comment: yes i changed it now error showing this word "Undefined variable: id"

Comment: @Copain remove the next line too.

Comment: this line?  $student = Student::find($id, ['id', 'studentname']);

Comment: another error now the red highlight pointing to my view and this is the error saiys " Trying to get property of non-object "

Comment: @Copain it's not related to the original issue. It means you have another error in the code. If you don't know how to fix this one, please show the error message. But before that, please update the relationship as I've shown in the answer.

Comment: i have edited my question please check i have done all the answer that u suggest..

Comment: @Copain this error is caused by wrong relationship or an account with wrong `student_id`. I've updated the answer. You need to fix the relationship and use `optional()` helper for accounts that do not belong to any real student.

Comment: yeah i have a zero value in my database maybe that one is causing the problem ill try to delete it

Comment: i mean the student id is 0

Comment: Wow it works haha the word optional is the answer thank you so much.. but do u know how to correct my codes or which part is wrong there